# Nested Query for Prometheus

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I want to query Prometheus, as
if my cluster metric exceeds some threshold then I want to check which of my hosts are exceeding a specific threshold, and eventually fire a script based on that for the host.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a label called `cluster`, then you can do:

```
metric > 5 and on (cluster) avg by (cluster)(metric > 10)
```

If the metric averages over 10 for the cluster, it'll return each instance that is over 5.